# "average length of the sequences in a fasta file": Can you improve this Erlang code?

Tags: string, erlang, sequence, bioinformatics, mean

I'm trying to get the mean length of [fasta sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasta_Sequence) using **Erlang**. A fasta file looks like this

```
>title1
ATGACTAGCTAGCAGCGATCGACCGTCGTACGC
ATCGATCGCATCGATGCTACGATCGATCATATA
ATGACTAGCTAGCAGCGATCGACCGTCGTACGC
ATCGATCGCATCGATGCTACGATCTCGTACGC
>title2
ATCGATCGCATCGATGCTACGATCTCGTACGC
ATGACTAGCTAGCAGCGATCGACCGTCGTACGC
ATCGATCGCATCGATGCTACGATCGATCATATA
ATGACTAGCTAGCAGCGATCGACCGTCGTACGC
>title3
ATCGATCGCATCGAT(...)
```

I tried to answser this question using the following **Erlang** code:

```
-module(golf).
-export([test/0]).

line([],{Sequences,Total}) ->  {Sequences,Total};
line(">" ++ Rest,{Sequences,Total}) -> {Sequences+1,Total};
line(L,{Sequences,Total}) -> {Sequences,Total+string:len(string:strip(L))}.

scanLines(S,Sequences,Total)->
        case io:get_line(S,'') of
            eof -> {Sequences,Total};
            {error,_} ->{Sequences,Total};
            Line -> {S2,T2}=line(Line,{Sequences,Total}), scanLines(S,S2,T2)
        end  .

test()->
    {Sequences,Total}=scanLines(standard_io,0,0),
    io:format("~p\n",[Total/(1.0*Sequences)]),
    halt().
```

**Compilation/Execution**:

```
erlc golf.erl
erl -noshell -s golf test < sequence.fasta
563.16
```

this code seems to work fine for a small fasta file but it takes hours to parse a larger one (>100Mo). Why ? I'm an Erlang newbie, can you please improve this code ?

Comment: See also the original 'challenge': http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/1759

Comment: Wow, excellent collection of non-trivial code samples from a wide array of languages. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need really fast IO then you have to do little bit more trickery than usual.

```
-module(g).
-export([s/0]).
s()->
  P = open_port({fd, 0, 1}, [in, binary, {line, 256}]),
  r(P, 0, 0),
  halt().
r(P, C, L) ->
  receive
    {P, {data, {eol, <<$>:8, _/binary>>}}} ->
      r(P, C+1, L);
    {P, {data, {eol, Line}}} ->
      r(P, C, L + size(Line));
    {'EXIT', P, normal} ->
      io:format("~p~n",[L/C])
  end.
```

It is fastest IO as I know but note `-noshell -noinput`.
Compile just like `erlc +native +"{hipe, [o3]}" g.erl` but with `-smp disable`

```
erl -smp disable -noinput -mode minimal -boot start_clean -s erl_compile compile_cmdline @cwd /home/hynek/Download @option native @option '{hipe, [o3]}' @files g.erl
```

and run:

```
time erl -smp disable -noshell -mode minimal -boot start_clean -noinput -s g s < uniprot_sprot.fasta
352.6697028442464

real    0m3.241s
user    0m3.060s
sys     0m0.124s
```

With `-smp enable` but native it takes:

```
$ erlc +native +"{hipe, [o3]}" g.erl
$ time erl -noshell -mode minimal -boot start_clean -noinput -s g s<uniprot_sprot.fasta
352.6697028442464

real    0m5.103s
user    0m4.944s
sys     0m0.112s
```

Byte code but with `-smp disable` (almost in par with native because most of work is done in port!):

```
$ erlc g.erl
$ time erl -smp disable -noshell -mode minimal -boot start_clean -noinput -s g s<uniprot_sprot.fasta
352.6697028442464

real    0m3.565s
user    0m3.436s
sys     0m0.104s
```

Just for completeness byte code with smp:

```
$ time erl -noshell -mode minimal -boot start_clean -noinput -s g s<uniprot_sprot.fasta 
352.6697028442464

real    0m5.433s
user    0m5.236s
sys     0m0.128s
```

For comparison [sarnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377270/sarnold) [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296855/average-length-of-the-sequences-in-a-fasta-file-can-you-improve-this-erlang-co/3296952#3296952) gives me wrong answer and takes more on same HW:

```
$ erl -smp disable -noinput -mode minimal -boot start_clean -s erl_compile compile_cmdline @cwd /home/hynek/Download @option native @option '{hipe, [o3]}' @files golf.erl
./golf.erl:5: Warning: variable 'Rest' is unused
$ time erl -smp disable -noshell -mode minimal -s golf test
359.04679841439776

real    0m17.569s
user    0m16.749s
sys     0m0.664s
```

**EDIT**: I have looked at characteristics of `uniprot_sprot.fasta` and I'm little bit surprised. It is 3824397 rows and 232MB. It means that `-smp disabled` version can handle 1.18 million text lines per second (71MB/s in line oriented IO).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the example; can you point out why our versions are getting different answers? Thanks!

Comment: @sarnold: I have not have enough time to look to your version where is problem. I guess it is trailing "\n" which may be is not stripped out by `string:strip/1` but I'm not sure. I checked by this code `perl -nle'/^>/?$c++:($b+=length((/(\S*)/)[0]))}{print$b/$c'` to be sure that mine version has not same bug as all others on http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/1759 but all seems ok and 352.6697028442464 should be right answer.

Comment: @sarnold: Very simple check tells me that trailing "\n" is it. When you subtract one from each line length you get right answer so it means `file:read_line/1` returns line with new line char and `string:strip/1` doesn't remove it.

Comment: thanks! I couldn't figure out where our versions were making different calculations...

Answer (score 3):

I too am learning Erlang, thanks for the fun question.

I understand working with Erlang strings as lists of characters can be very slow; if you can [work with binaries](http://www.erlang.org/faq/academic.html#string-performance) instead you should see some performance gains. I don't know how you would use arbitrary-length strings with binaries, but if you can sort it out, it should help.

Also, if you don't mind working with a file directly rather than `standard_io`, perhaps you could speed things along by using `file:open(..., [raw, read_ahead])`. `raw` means the file must be on the local node's filesystem, and `read_ahead` specifies that Erlang should perform file IO with a buffer. (Think of using C's stdio facilities with and without buffering.)

I'd expect the `read_ahead` to make the most difference, but everything with Erlang includes the phrase "benchmark before guessing".

**EDIT**

Using `file:open("uniprot_sprot.fasta", [read, read_ahead])` gets `1m31s` on the full uniprot_sprot.fasta dataset. (Average 359.04679841439776.)

Using `file:open(.., [read, read_ahead])` and `file:read_line(S)`, I get `0m34s`.

Using `file:open(.., [read, read_ahead, raw])` and `file:read_line(S)`, I get `0m9s`. Yes, nine seconds.

Here's where I stand now; if you can figure out how to use binaries instead of lists, it might see still more improvement:

```
-module(golf).
-export([test/0]).

line([],{Sequences,Total}) ->  {Sequences,Total};
line(">" ++ Rest,{Sequences,Total}) -> {Sequences+1,Total};
line(L,{Sequences,Total}) -> {Sequences,Total+string:len(string:strip(L))}.

scanLines(S,Sequences,Total)->
        case file:read_line(S) of
            eof -> {Sequences,Total};
            {error,_} ->{Sequences,Total};
            {ok, Line} -> {S2,T2}=line(Line,{Sequences,Total}), scanLines(S,S2,T2)
        end  .

test()->
    F = file:open("/home/sarnold/tmp/uniprot_sprot.fasta", [read, read_ahead, raw]),
    case F of
    { ok, File } -> 
        {Sequences,Total}=scanLines(File,0,0),
        io:format("~p\n",[Total/(1.0*Sequences)]);
    { error, Reason } ->
            io:format("~s", Reason)
    end,
    halt().
```

Comment: Thanks Arnold, I'm currently testing you solution. erl (version= R13B01) raised an error :" {"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{file,read_line,[{file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.286>,7}}]},{golf,scanLines,3},{golf,test,0},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}" . Any idea ?

Comment: Ok, I've told that my version doesn't support R13B01, I will test this tomorrow on another computer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your big performance problems have been solved by opening the file in raw mode, but here's some more thoughts if you need to optimise that code further.

Learn and use fprof.

You're using `string:strip/1` primarily to remove the trailing newline. As erlang values are immutable you have to make a complete copy of the list (with all the associated memory allocation) just to remove the last character.  If you know the file is well formed, just subtract one from your count, otherwise I'd try writing a length function the counts the number of relevant characters and ignores irrelevant ones.

I'm wary of advice that says binaries are better than lists, but given how little processing you it's probably the case here.  The first steps are to open the file in binary mode and using `erlang:size/1` to find the length.

It won't affect performance (significantly), but the multiplication by 1.0 in `Total/(1.0*Sequences)` is only necessary in languages with broken division.  Erlang division works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The call `string:len(string:strip(L))` traverses the list at least twice (I'm unaware of the string:strip implementation). Instead you could write a simple function to count the line length w/0 the spaces:

```
stripped_len(L) ->
  stripped_len(L, 0).

stripped_len([$ |L], Len) ->
  stripped_len(L, Len);

stripped_len([_C|L], Len) ->
  stripped_len(L, Len + 1);

stripped_len([], Len) ->
  Len.
```

The same method can be applied to binaries as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Elixir (elixir-lang.org) which is runs on top of Erlang and has a syntax similar to Ruby. Elixir solves String problems in the following way:

> Elixir strings are UTF8 binaries, with all the raw speed and memory
>   savings that brings. Elixir has a String module with Unicode
>   functionality built-in and is a great example of writing code that
>   writes code. String.Unicode reads various Unicode database dumps such
>   as UnicodeData.txt to dynamically generate Unicode functions for the
>   String module built straight from that data! (http://devintorr.es/blog/2013/01/22/the-excitement-of-elixir/)

Just wonder whether Elixir would be faster?

Comment: You should not guess but measure.