# Improving clojure lazy-seq usage for iterative text parsing

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, bioinformatics

I'm writing a Clojure implementation of [this coding challenge](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/code-golf-mean-length-of-fasta-sequences), attempting to find the average length of sequence records in Fasta format:

```
>1
GATCGA
GTC
>2
GCA
>3
AAAAA
```

For more background see this [related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296855/average-length-of-the-sequences-in-a-fasta-file-can-you-improve-this-erlang-co) about an Erlang solution.

My beginner Clojure attempt uses lazy-seq to attempt to read in the file one record at a time so it will scale to large files. However it is fairly memory hungry and slow, so I suspect that it's not implemented optimally. Here is a solution using the [BioJava](http://biojava.org) library to abstract out the parsing of the records:

```
(import '(org.biojava.bio.seq.io SeqIOTools))
(use '[clojure.contrib.duck-streams :only (reader)])

(defn seq-lengths [seq-iter]
  "Produce a lazy collection of sequence lengths given a BioJava StreamReader"
  (lazy-seq
    (if (.hasNext seq-iter)
      (cons (.length (.nextSequence seq-iter)) (seq-lengths seq-iter)))))

(defn fasta-to-lengths [in-file seq-type]
  "Use BioJava to read a Fasta input file as a StreamReader of sequences"
  (seq-lengths (SeqIOTools/fileToBiojava "fasta" seq-type (reader in-file))))

(defn average [coll]
  (/ (reduce + coll) (count coll)))

(when *command-line-args*
  (println
    (average (apply fasta-to-lengths *command-line-args*))))
```

and an equivalent approach without external libraries:

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.duck-streams :only (read-lines)])

(defn seq-lengths [lines cur-length]
  "Retrieve lengths of sequences in the file using line lengths"
  (lazy-seq
    (let [cur-line (first lines)
          remain-lines (rest lines)]
      (if (= nil cur-line) [cur-length]
        (if (= \> (first cur-line))
          (cons cur-length (seq-lengths remain-lines 0))
          (seq-lengths remain-lines (+ cur-length (.length cur-line))))))))

(defn fasta-to-lengths-bland [in-file seq-type]
  ; pop off first item since it will be everything up to the first >
  (rest (seq-lengths (read-lines in-file) 0)))

(defn average [coll]
  (/ (reduce + coll) (count coll)))

(when *command-line-args*
  (println
    (average (apply fasta-to-lengths-bland *command-line-args*))))
```

The current implementation takes 44 seconds on a large file compared to 7 seconds for a Python implementation. Can you offer any suggestions on speeding the code up and making it more intuitive? Is the usage of lazy-seq correctly parsing the file record by record as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably doesn't matter, but `average` is holding onto the head of the seq of lengths.
The following is a wholly untested, but lazier way to do what I think you want.

```
(use 'clojure.java.io) ;' since 1.2

(defn lazy-avg [coll]
  (let [f (fn [[v c] val] [(+ v val) (inc c)])
        [sum cnt] (reduce f [0 0] coll)]
    (if (zero? cnt) 0 (/ sum cnt)))

(defn fasta-avg [f]
  (->> (reader f) 
    line-seq
    (filter #(not (.startsWith % ">")))
    (map #(.length %))
    lazy-avg))
```

Comment: Actually I think this is quite likely to matter with large datasets... I even posted an answer pointing this out previously, but then suggested a ridiculous way of dealing with the problem in a momentary lapse of reason -- +1 for the correct solution to this one.

Comment: I think groups lines between the >s are to be considered as single records, though; something like `(partition-by #(.startsWith ^String % ">"))` might help. The general idea remains the same.

Comment: ataggart and Michal, many thanks for these pointers. With them, here is a cleaner version that finishes in 1/4 the time: http://gist.github.com/485853. This is about 2x slower than my Python version, including JVM start up time from the commandline. I'm learning a lot from this exercise; if there are other apparent areas for improvement please let me know and I can iterate over another version.

Comment: How is `lazy-avg` lazy and `average` not? Both of them evaluate the whole collection passed to them when they are called.

Comment: The difference is that average calls count which runs down the entire seq, thus the entire seq needs to be in memory at once. lazy-avg carries the cumulative size with it on each iteration, thus after each step the previous elements can be garbage collected.

Comment: Shouldn't reader be closed explicitly (e.g. with "with-open")?

Answer (score 1):

Your `average` function is non-lazy -- it needs to realise the entire `coll` argument while holding onto its head. *Update:* Just realised that my original answer included a nonsensical suggestion as to how to solve the above problem... argh. Fortunately ataggart has since posted a correct solution.

Other than that, your code does seem lazy at first glance, though the use of `read-lines` is currently discouraged (use `line-seq` instead).

If the file is really large and your functions will be called a large number of times, type-hinting `seq-iter` in the argument vector of `seq-length` -- `^NameOfBiojavaSeqIterClass seq-iter`, use `#^` in place of `^` if you're on Clojure 1.1 -- might make a significant difference. In fact, `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)`, *then* compile your code and add type hints to remove all reflection warnings.